# SpaceVim jdt-language-server-latest

Tags: java, eclipse, neovim, spacevim

I am using SpaceVim as Java IDE, *just for fun*. While configuring [ISP](https://spacevim.org/layers/language-server-protocol/#install), a nice-to-have allowing to fully enjoy many of IDEs' typical features, I found that the following windows based step:

```
[[layers]]
  name = "lsp"
  filetypes = [
    "java"
  ]
  [layers.override_cmd]
    java = [
    "java",
    "-Declipse.application=org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.id1",
    "-Dosgi.bundles.defaultStartLevel=4",
    "-Declipse.product=org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.product",
    "-Dlog.protocol=true",
    "-Dlog.level=NONE",
    "-noverify",
    "-Xmx1G",
    "-jar",
    "D:\\dev\\jdt-language-server-latest\\plugins\\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.5.200.v20180922-1751.jar",
    "-configuration",
    "D:\\dev\\jdt-language-server-latest\\config_win",
    "-data",
    "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\.cache\\javalsp"
    ]
```

How do I translate it on linux? Aside for the flag `config_linux`, I clearly cannot find `D:\\...`, `C:\\...` equivalency in my system, nor a folder such as `jdt-language-server-latest`. From [Eclipse](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse.jdt.ls) dedicated page, I am not able to deduce relevant information. Maybe because of my lack of experience. Thanks in advance for any hint.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. download latest version of jdt-language-server from https://download.eclipse.org/jdtls/milestones/
2. unpackage the file
3. config like this

```
    "-jar",
        "/home/kerwin/jdt-language-server/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.4.0.v20161219-1356.jar",
        "-configuration",
        "/home/kerwin/jdt-language-server/config_linux",
        "-data",
        "/home/kerwin/.cache/javalsp"
```

4. enjoy it!

Comment: What is javalsp i don't have it in .cache folder